# Connect an Arduino to the door ajax, to get alarm when door is opened

Tags: alarm, outlander

I'm a software developer, and my previous car was stolen. For my next car I would like to build a system that make an alarm sound, when someone is opening a door, without first click in a remote control.

I can buy an Arduino, hide it in the car, and develop in in the way I need. The input should be the RC signal and when the door is opened. It will be connected to a buzzer. My only question is how to get notified when one of the door opened?

I know there is something called door ajar, that signal the car when door is opened?

Is it possibile to connect to it? If so, where can I find more information, where it should be and how it should look like? What protocol is used for that signal?

Comment: Why not just plumb it into the two wires of the door switch? There should be a plunger switch for the door somewhere in the door jamb or it may be based within the latch. Either way, simple interrupt circuit on the Arduino and you have it done.

Comment: At 50 meters, no one will hear a buzzer attached to an Arduino. You'll have to attach an H-bridge speaker driver and a high power speaker for any meaningful sound output. But for less than the cost of an Arduino, H-bridge and speaker, you can buy a car alarm with remotes and a really loud speaker. No software development, no experimentation, 1 hour to install. Just a suggestion! Listen, software development is one of my passions too, but you know the saying: For a man with a hammer, everything looks like a nail. For best results, just buy a car alarm.

Comment: In addition to suggestions and ideas given some vehicle manufacturers already have factory engine immobilizers, timed alarm for flashing headlights and sounding horns and lastly, cellular connection to alert the owner of a theft attempt. Cellular connection to a vehicle will allow remote starting from around the world, status check of vehicle, and more. Aftermarket antitheft/alarm systems can be inexpensive to pricey with the remote alerting owner's of a theft attempt. The lowest cost antitheft device; manual transmission and/or starting circuit on/off switch.